# Create new contracts from a contract Vyper

Tags: smartcontracts, vyper

Is there any way to create any child contracts from a contract, example when someone call "createChildContract()" function. In solidity, simply using **new** operator sold the problem, how about vyper? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my question:

```
create_forwarder_to()
```

Example at [Uniswap's contract factory](https://github.com/Uniswap/contracts-vyper/blob/master/contracts/uniswap_factory.vy)